# How do I write the code without "strtotime"

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I write this code without `strtotime` conversion.

The date of birth come from database.I want to display it in `d/m/y` format

```
<?php 
  echo  date('d/m/Y', strtotime($form_data["personal_info"]->date_of_birth)) ;
    ?>
```

Comment: what is the value of $form_data["personal_info"]->date_of_birth ?

Comment: Y/m/d format(db format)

Comment: First of all, we need know what is $form_data["personal_info"]->date_of_birth. Is it mysql datetime or date type?

Comment: @felipsmartins datetime type

Comment: @Ann is it like this: 2015-12-28, for exemple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be work:

```
$stringDate = '2015-09-22'; # maybe a MySQL date string

echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $stringDate)->format('d/m/Y');
```

Procedural style:

```
echo  date_format(date_create_from_format('Y-m-d',$stringDate), 'd/m/Y');
```

Even though it seems verbose, it turns on the code a lot more explicit. Someone who reading this code at first glance can understand what is going on.
But if you're just concerned  about concise code, it's okay using strtotime().

Also, you can format date via SQL (MySQL):

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-22', '%d/%m/%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-22', '%d/%m/%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 22/09/2015                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

Despite it has influence on cache.

Comment: <?php $stringDate = $form_data["personal_info"]->date_of_birth;

echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', $stringDate)->format('d/m/Y'); ?>

Comment: @Ann "One is happy to be of service" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Carbon a simple PHP extension Find more details here [Click to find more details](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
public function getDobAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
    }

    public function setDobAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['dob'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->toDateString();
    }
```

Comment: Should be noted that `Carbon` is a **library** and not an **extension**. While Carbon is great for some date manipulation, for simple formatting it's a bit overkill.